# Creating array in web forms using c#

Tags: c#

I'm new to c#. I need to use an array in asp.net website using c#. I'm trying a binary 
search program in asp.net website. I have written the program in console application using
one dimensional array. Now I'm trying to use the same array concept in website.
I have created a text box for the user to enter the size of the array and a button which 
takes the numeric input entered in the text box to create an array of mentioned size. My 
main question is what should i need to use in VS2010 so that user can enter the elements 
of the array??

Comment: Poor example of a question it would actually help if you show the code that you have written and what you are trying to do..

Answer (score 0):

So ..... You should use Repeater Control.
You can find how to use it here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzx23804(v=vs.85).aspx